# Type mismatch in Scala(hasNext function)

Tags: scala

I have a type mismatch in the 'while(blocks.hasNext)' function

```
def encrypt(file: String): Array[Byte] = { 

    val text = Source.fromFile(file)
    val list=text.toList    
    val blocks=list.grouped(501)

    while(blocks.hasNext) {
          val block0=blocks.next()    
          val stringBlock=block0.mkString
          val arrayBytes=stringBlock.getBytes
    }
}
```

The error says "type mismatch;found:Unit,required:Array[Byte]". Where is the problem?

Comment: because your return type is Array[Byte] but you are returning Void (aka Unit)

Comment: by the way are you trying to read a file here??

Comment: @prayagupd Yes，I read a file in my main function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not return anything you stored the data in variables try this

```
def encrypt(file: String): Array[Byte] = { 
    val text = Source.fromFile(file)
    val list=text.toList
    val blocks=list.grouped(501).toArray
blocks.flatMap{block0 =>
       val stringBlock=block0.mkString
       stringBlock.getBytes
      }
}
```

now flatMap will return result as `Array[Byte]` type

Hope this works for you

Comment: I have tried it & your answer seems to mismatch type as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change the while loop to :

```
blocks.flatMap(_.mkString.getBytes).toArray
```